# How to arrange pixel address as order under certain condition?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am currently doing map processing in matlab. Now i solved the maze and get the path of maze. Now i have turning point in map. But this address pixel are not in correct order. So i want to order the incorrect order of pixel address in to correct order.

INCORRECT ORDER:

```
shape(1).cen=[28;136];
shape(2).cen=[122;136];
shape(3).cen=[344;391];
shape(4).cen=[548;493];
shape(5).cen=[548;191];
shape(6).cen=[344;191];
shape(7).cen=[122;391];
```

CORRECT ORDR:

```
map(1).cen=[28;136];
map(2).cen=[122;136];
map(3).cen=[122;391];
map(4).cen=[344;391];
map(5).cen=[344;191];
map(6).cen=[548;191];
map(7).cen=[548;493];
```

My code is below:-

```
  `map(1).cen=[28;136];
 o=0; order=1;xflag=0;yflag=0; 
 k=length(shape); %indicates the total elements in shape.cen structure
for (j=1:k)
order=order+1; o=o+1;
if (j==1)
    x=map(1).cen(1,1);
    y=map(1).cen(2,1);
    for(i=1:k)
        xi=shape(i).cen(1,1);
        yi=shape(i).cen(2,1);
        if((x==xi)||(y==yi))
            if(x==xi)
                map(order).cen(1,1)=xi;
                map(order).cen(2,1)=yi;
                xflag=1;
                break;
            else
                (y==yi)
                map(order).cen(1,1)=xi;
                map(order).cen(2,1)=yi;
                yflag=1;
                break;
            end
        end
    end
end

x=map(o).cen(1,1);
y=map(o).cen(2,1);

for(i=1:k)
    xi=shape(i).cen(1,1);
    yi=shape(i).cen(2,1);
    if(xflag==1)
        if(y==yi)
            map(order).cen(1,1)=xi;
            map(order).cen(2,1)=yi;
            xflag=0;
            yflag=1;
            break;
        end
    end

    if (yflag==1)
        if(x==xi)
            map(order).cen(1,1)=xi;
            map(order).cen(2,1)=yi;
            xflag=1;
            yflag=0;
            break;
        end
    end
end
end
```

`

Comment: If you speak about 'order' than you must somehow sort them. What do you sort by? From the example it seems you sort them in increasing order based on value of first coordinate?

Comment: check out [sortrows](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[shape.cen]'` will give you the following array:

```
ans =
    28   136
   122   136
   344   391
   548   493
   548   191
   344   191
   122   391
```

Now that it's a regular numerical array, you can use [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/stats/ordinal.sortrows.html), like this.

```
map = sortrows([shape.cen]')
```

to get:

```
map =
    28   136
   122   136
   122   391
   344   191
   344   391
   548   191
   548   493
```

If you don't want it as a numerical array, but a struct similar to `shape`, you can do:

```
[~, ID] = sortrows([shape.cen]')
map = shape(ID)'
```